# How do I display specific fields from json file in a table with data?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3

I have around 300 records like this. Now it displays all items in the table. I want only Name,
proteins and kcal to be displayed in my table. How do I do this? I am fetching the list from an API.

```
[
   {
      "id":"711113fb-c3d1-46db-9f08-737a66ba643d",
      "name":"Banana",
      "fats":"0.2",
      "carbohydrates":"11.8",
      "proteins":"0.8",
      "kcal":"46",
      "tags":[
         
      ],
      "tag_ids":[
         
      ],
      "diet_phases":[
         
      ],
      "diet_phase_ids":[
         
      ],
      "product_group_id":"1cad5993-78f8-43b0-a0c5-f6f88fdf53b8",
      "product_group_name":"Fruits"
   },
```

```
      productList: (state) => state.products.list,
```

This.items is an array which holds the items in my table.

mounted:   `this.fetchProducts().then(() => { this.items = this.productList; }); },`

...mapActions ({
fetchProducts: "products/fetch",})

```
actions: {
    fetch({ commit }) {
      return api.products.list({}).then(({ data }) => {
        commit(SET_LIST, data.results);
      });
    },
```

Comment: You are not showing how you actually render the table at the moment, but you can easily loop over the records and then only render a `<td>` for the fields you want. Or you can use this nice table component: https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/

Comment: I've stated that I render the items in an array `this.items: []` , I am using bootstrap-vue table component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still missing the template part of your component, and I don't know the bootstrap-vue table. So I assume your `this.items` just renders out each key of your item object.
So you want to controll what is rendered in the JS code and not the template, you can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. So instead of directly assigning it to `this.items`, you can do something like this:

```
this.items = this.productList.map((item) => {
    return {
        name: item.name,
        proteins: item.proteins,
        kcal: item.kcal,
    };
});
```